# Recreate child controls and ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, composite-controls, childcontrol

Lets explain the problem with a simple case:

Lets CC be a composite control.

CC has a variable called filter (string) stored in viewState.

CC has 2 static child controls:

- searchBox: Textbox
- searchButton: Button

The user type a search term and click on the searchButton.

the following steps happens:

- PageLoad
- CreateChildControls:

  - Create static child controls
  - Request database using filter
  - Create table with results and insert on each row an editButton (Button) and binding     handler to the editButtons click event.
  - Insert table in childControls hierarchy.
- Click event is fired

searchButton_click handler does the following:

- update the filter
- **Recreate child controls** *this is where I am stucked*

I need to recreate the child control hierarchy but also to maintain the child controls viewstate ! Otherwise, my editButtons's Click events will not be fired at all.

Is there a way to achieve this ?
I keep searching but I cannot find any solution. I will be glad to get some help from you guys.

Hope you anderstand my problem, ask questions/code illustration if needed.

Best regards

Quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have found a solution:

The trick was to give an ID to each editButton (string.format("editButton_{0}", i).

If you have better solution, please let me know.